# Printing in perfect Columns in Android Studio

Tags: android, printing

I am in the middle of an assignment that requires me to print out a league table of football both in eclipse and android studio. When I use the following code in eclipse it lines everything up perfectly but when used in android produces the following results:

```
public void printResults(InputStream here){
    Main letsRun = new Main(here);
    results = letsRun.runCode();
    String presentation = "";
    StringBuilder bld = new StringBuilder();
    String results2 = "";
    presentation = "TEAM NAME     Wins   Draws   Losses   Points" + "\n";
    for(Standings test : results){
        String test2 = test.getTeam() +"    " + test.getWins() +"          " + test.getDraws()+"          " + test.getLosses() +"          "+test.getPoints() +"\n";
        bld.append(test2);
    }

    results2 = bld.toString();

    presentation += "The percentage of games predicted successfully for this season was: " + letsRun.getSuccessfullyPredicted();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DisplayResults.class);
    intent.putExtra("KEY", presentation);
    intent.putExtra("results", results2);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

[ResultsProducedByAndroid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9Gc9.png)

I have tried using String.format() but that doesnt seem to want to work for me either and Im wondering does anyone have a way to make all the columns line up perfectly in android?

Comment: use monospace (seriously it will work) ... but more seriously ... tables(with columns) are so bad on Android (remeber that you have to support multiple device's sizes)  ... use some ListView or RecyclerView with nice card instead

Comment: @Selvin How do I set my text to be monospace? Do I do it in the TextView box in android studio or do I do it to the actual file?

Comment: by setting typeface of TextView

Comment: @Selvin I love you! Works prefectly thanks so much :)

Comment: Please, tell me that you only wana just check it or show some prototype and you will not use it in production.... It's a terrible idea ... look at cw's answer for better solution

Comment: @Selvin Its literally only being usd for assignment... not going into production

Answer (score 0):

ASCII art — including tables such as yours — requires a monospace font.

One approach, therefore, is to stick with your existing code, but use a monospace font when displaying that output.

Better approaches include:

- Using a `TableLayout` to create an actual table
- Using HTML and appropriate tags (e.g., `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>`) to create an actual table